# Открытие и закрытие меню при нажатии на ссылку

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Хочу сделать чтоб при нажатии на ссылку появлялись еще пункты меню, а после, если кликнуть на эту ссылку еще раз - это же меню исчезает.

Вот код:

```css
.sub-menu 
{ 
   display: none; 
} 
.main-item:focus ~ .sub-menu, 
.main-item:active ~ .sub-menu, 
.sub-menu:hover 
{ 
   display: block; 
}
```

```html
<a class="main-item" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="1" >Открыть подменю</a> 
<ul class="sub-menu"> 
   <li><a href="#1">подпункт 1</a></li> 
   <li><a href="#2">подпункт 2</a></li> 
   <li><a href="#3">подпункт 3</a></li> 
</ul>
```

И все бы хорошо - но при нажатии на ссылку меню не скрывается. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function toggle(el)
{
 el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<a onclick="toggle(document.getElementById('sub-menu'))">Открыть подменю</a>
<ul id="sub-menu" style="display:none">
 <li><a href="#1">подпункт 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#2">подпункт 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#3">подпункт 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: в таком случае меню не пропадает приклике в любом месте экрана

Comment: Да, ведь вопрос был "кликнуть на ссылку повторно чтобы закрыть подменю".

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать вот так без js:

```css
.sub-menu 
{ 
   display: none; 
} 
.main-item {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #333
}
#submenu:target { 
   display: block; 
}
```

```html
<a href="#submenu" class="main-item" tabindex="1" >Открыть подменю</a> 
<ul id='submenu' class="sub-menu"> 
   <li><a href="#1">подпункт 1</a></li> 
   <li><a href="#2">подпункт 2</a></li> 
   <li><a href="#3">подпункт 3</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".js").click(function(){
        $(".js").hide();
        $("ul>li>ul").hide();
    });
 
 
 
    $("ul>li:nth-child(3)").click(function(){
        $(".js").show();
        $("ul>li>ul").show();
    });
});
```

```css
ul>li{
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
ul ul{
  position:absolute;
  top:20px; left:-40px;
  width:100px;
  z-index:10;
  display:none;
}
ul li ul li{
  display:block;
  border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
}
.js{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:9;
  display:none;
  background:transparent;
}
a{
  color:blue;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
li{
   text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul> 
  <li><a href="">Ссылка 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Ссылка 2</a></li>
  <li><a>Ссылка 3</a> 
<ul> 
  <li><a href="">Ссылка 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Ссылка 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Ссылка 3</a></li>
</ul>  
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="js"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

вот так по клику в любом месте